# Problema al Ejecutar JAR de JDeveloper con Librerias Externas

Tags: java, jcalendar, jdeveloper, manifest

Buenas tardes estoy usando la Libreria de JCalendar 1.4 de toedter en una aplicación y cuando hago Run de la misma en la IDE JDeveloper funciona correctamente, pero cuando genero el .Jar esta no se ejecuta cuando el programa usa dichas librerias, esto lo comprobe ya que cree el jar sin los componentes de JCalendar y funcionaba, por ende necesito saber si alguien de esta comunidad conoce la manera de incluir librerias externas en la creacion del Jar en Oracle JDeveloper.
Muchas gracias

```
[07:19:35 PM] ----  Deployment started.  ----
[07:19:35 PM] Target platform is Standard Java EE.
[07:19:35 PM] Running dependency analysis...
[07:19:35 PM] Building...
[07:19:35 PM] Deploying profile...
[07:19:35 PM] Deployment cancelled.
[07:19:35 PM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[07:19:35 PM] ERROR: Error while merging Manifest from file:/D:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/lib/jcalendar-1.4.jar!/com/toedter/calendar/JMonthChooser1.class: invalid header field
[07:19:35 PM] ERROR: Error while merging Manifest from file:/D:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/lib/jcalendar-1.4.jar!/com/toedter/calendar/JMonthChooser1.class: invalid header field
```

esto me da la consola cuando trato de incluir las librerias desde el deployment profile

Comment: Ya resolviste el problema?

Comment: @RaulCacacho no, tuve que "hacer" la librería externa por mi cuenta, JDeveloper tiene muy poca documentación. Igual si tiene la solución me gustaría saberla! Gracias por Preguntar.

Comment: @RaulCacacho no, tuve que "hacer" la librería externa por mi cuenta, JDeveloper tiene muy poca documentación. Igual si tiene la solución me gustaría saberla! Gracias por Preguntar.

Comment: Posiblemente el problema sea porque su manifest declara la clase principal mediante `Main-Class: com.toedter.calendar.demo.JCalendarDemo`, te sugiero probar con mi versión de JCalendar https://github.com/javatlacati/jcalendar/